# Control 4 Grove - RGB LED (WS2813 Mini) color and brightness

Tags: rgb-led

I have connected 4 Grove - RGB LED (WS2813 Mini) to D2,D3,D4,D5 on Grove Base Shield V2.0 for Arduino. How can I control the brightness and color of each LED? At the moment I only know to activated one.

Code:

```
#include "Adafruit_NeoPixel.h"
#define PIN            2
#define NUMPIXELS      1 
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
  
void setup() {
  pixels.setBrightness(125);
  pixels.begin();  
}
 
void loop() {
    pixels.setPixelColor(1, pixels.Color(255,255,255));  
    pixels.show();  
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the multiple ways possible to address the problem, Basically, use a for loop and iterate the first parameter setPixelColor function to address all the LEDs. Try experimenting [here](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/303848371358007874):

```
#include "Adafruit_NeoPixel.h"
#define PIN            2
#define NUMPIXELS      4
Adafruit_NeoPixel pixels = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  pixels.setBrightness(125);
  pixels.begin();
}

void loop()
{
  pixels.clear(); // Set all pixel colors to 'off'

  // The first NeoPixel in a strand is #0, second is 1, all the way up
  // to the count of pixels minus one.
  for (int i = 0; i < NUMPIXELS; i++) { // For each pixel...

    // pixels.Color() takes RGB values, from 0,0,0 up to 255,255,255
    // Here we're using a moderately bright green color:
    pixels.setPixelColor(i, pixels.Color(0, random(0,255), 0));

    pixels.show();   // Send the updated pixel colors to the hardware.

    delay(100); // Pause before next pass through loop
  }
}
```

here is quick view:

[image]

> Since you are using NeoPixels, [here](https://wokwi.com/arduino/libraries/Adafruit_NeoPixel) is a list of simulated examples. you can play with the code and make your own projects online.

Comment: Thanks but the simulation is wrong as I have  4 Grove - RGB LED (WS2813 Mini) (https://www.seeedstudio.com/Grove-RGB-LED-WS2813-Mini-p-4269.html ) connected to D2,D3,D4,D5 and I wish to control each one of them separately.

Comment: @alirazi And why would you need 4 pins for that? As I see it the WS2813 is just like the standard Neopixels (WS2811 or 12 I think). You can daisy chain them. That way you only need one pin, but you can still control each LED individually.

Comment: @chrisl You are right, but I wish to avoid soldering and extra wires.

Comment: https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/wiki/Multiple-Controller-Examples you have a few examples for controlling multiple addressable LEDs